# conda: install dynamically linked python executable

Tags: python, anaconda, miniconda

I am trying to use miniconda to install a python driver executable that is dynamically linked to its libpython.so shared library, like the one installed on my system is. The easiest way to check whether the script is dynamically or statically linked is using ldd. For example:

```
(py3.9) /user/home/firl$ ldd $(which python3) | grep libpython # ldd of conda's python3.9 install: $CONDA_PREFIX/bin/python3
<no output>
(py3.9) /user/home/firl$ ldd /usr/bin/python3.9 | grep libpython # ldd of python3.9 system install: 
        libpython3.9.so.1.0 => /usr/lib64/libpython3.9.so.1.0 (0x00007f668ab73000)
```

Another way to check is using nm and grepping for symbols beginning with "Py". If it is statically linked, "Py" symbols will be present.

I read the conda docs, but as far as I'm aware, there is no option to toggle dynamic and static linking of the python executable installed by a package. I also looked at [condaforge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python/files?version=3.9.15&page=2) for different types of python packages to install, but as far as I can tell, there is only 1 python package for each arch+python release.

Does anyone know of a way to have conda install python packages with the dynamically linked version of the driver executable?

Thanks!